# Autohotkey : skip comment lines in Loop / FileReadLine

Tags: autohotkey

i read a config.ini with a location of some .exe to run, but i want to skip a comment line from my config.ini (cause i want to explain how to use the file), if someone can help me thanks

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance force
Loop
    {
    FileReadLine, exe, config.ini, %A_Index%
            if ErrorLevel 
            break
    Run %exe%
    Sleep , 300
    }
return
ExitApp
```

config.ini

```
// Put here location of your programs << line to skip
// Thanks << line to skip
C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe
C:\WINDOWS\****.exe
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Loop
    {
    FileReadLine, exe, config.ini, %A_Index%
            if ErrorLevel 
            break
            else if SubStr(exe,1,2)=="//"
            continue
    Run %exe%
    Sleep , 300
    }
```

Using [`SubStr()`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SubStr.htm) check if first two chars in line are `//` if so use [`continue`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Continue.htm) to skip rest of loop and start next iteration.